# light off in Google chrome while opening some web pages

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to open some web pages but the light off in chrome as illustrated in the following screen shot
[image]

**How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: is your chrome themed in someway it replaces css?

Comment: thank you @Lorenzo Von Matterhorn,if possible, how can I notice if it replaces CSS or not?

Comment: disable it to see if the problem goes away. if it does, it messes up with css, therefore making webpages with certain css colour information get that same information overwritten or replaced. extensions such as stylebot can do this and mess up your webpages.

Comment: is there an advert you have to close?

Comment: re my last comment, there wasn't an ad to close. Here is what it looks like on my computer  and clearly what it should look like  http://i.imgur.com/zDoAVNS.png  You could try saving it locally and if it's still dark then link a copy to http://ge.tt to see if anybody or you, can fiddle with the html/css/whatever, to see what is causing this

Comment: thank you very much @barlop for kind help
I tried two procedures:1)I saved the page locally and the problem still occurs because I let the page to complete its loading.
2)I saved the page locally and don't let it to complete its loading(stop loading after few seconds of opening the web page) .

Comment: Beside that it works very well in firefox but the saved copy still appears dark in firefox.
Here is a link to the saved page
http://ge.tt/58sADFs/v/0?c

Comment: @user2019510 what about the webpage saved from firefox(where it works well)?  be interesting if firefox since it displays it fine, saves it locally fine/nicely. Can you provide the URL. I googled from that link and got http://www.embedded.com/print/4006477  which funnily enough might be what you want to read, but isn't the link you had. It's difficult to find your original links sometimes.